# Show $\sum^\infty_{n=1}(\frac{x}{n^{0.6}(1+nx^2)})$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{x}{n^{0.6}(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Is $x\rightarrow\sum^\infty_{n=1}(\frac{x}{n^{0.6}(1+nx^2)})$ continuous at all points of $\mathbb{R}$?

I'm stuck on the first step, I feel I want to try and bound the expression inside the sum above. I've tried that and I'm not sure how.

I'm not that confident it is right either, because $x\sum^\infty_{n=1}(\frac{1}{n^{0.6}})$ doesn't converge.

IIRC $\frac{1}{x^p}$ converges for |p|>1, needs investigation for |p|=1 and doesn't converge for |p|<1 - from the ratio test.

Comment: Hint: you can prove the first assertion with Weierstrass M-test (find the maximum of the absolute value of the functions being summed by a simple derivative study: you will see that this boils down to $0.6+0.5>1$) and the answer to the question (yes) follows from that assertion.

Comment: @julien I know this sounds weird but the book prides itself on being in order, I officially don't know that test yet. Could I have a hint without?

Comment: Hmm... then estimate the remainder with the same technique (function study: the max is attained at $x=1/\sqrt{n}$ for each summand). This will give you a uniform estimate hence uniform convergence.

Comment: @julien uniform estimate? I'm new at real analysis sorry. I'd be very thankful if you could post these hints in an answer and flesh them out a bit.

Comment: Ok... but is this homework?

Comment: @julien no, it's in the "exercises" section of the book I am getting through. "Examples and theorems in analysis", it doesn't have solutions to the even numbered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n(x):=\frac{x}{n^{0.6}(1+nx^2)}\qquad f(x):=\sum_{n\geq 1}f_n(x)
$$

- Check that this series of functions converges pointwise over $\mathbb{R}$ (this means that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ fixed, the series converges: you'll have to treat the case $x=0$ which is trivial separately; for the case $n\neq 0$, note that $|f_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{xn^{1.6}}$)
- Check that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|=f_n(1/\sqrt{n})=\frac{1}{2n^{1.1}}$.
- Deduce from the latter that

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \big| f(x)-\sum_{n=1}^kf_n(x)\big|\leq \sum_{n\geq k+1} \frac{1}{2n^{1.1}}\longrightarrow 0$$
as $k\rightarrow +\infty$ which is precisely uniform convergence of this series of functions over $\mathbb{R}$ (we say that a sequence of functions $g_k$ converges to $g$ uniformly over a set $S$ if $\sup_{x\in S}|g_k(x)-g(x)|\longrightarrow 0$ as $k$ tends to $+\infty$; we say a series of functions converges uniformly if the sequence of partial sums converges uniformly).

- Now you have probably seen that the uniform limit of a sequence (or series) of continuous functions is continuous. Otherwise, this is a classical $\epsilon/3$ exercise which is most likely a theorem in your book.

Comment: @Alec Teal  Ok, I have posted a more detailed sketch. Do you know the result of the last bullet?

Comment: I hate to post again (the 10 or 25 rep I can give you for this is a tiny fraction of 29k) but what's the definition for pointwise convergence? The second one is that upper bound I couldn't find! (how did you find it) the $\rightarrow 0$ follows. What is the definition of "uniform convergence" (I keep seeing this word "uniform" in front of things)  (more to come)

Comment: @AlecTeal  Boy that's not an easy exercise if you don't know all these terms..;-)

Comment: With that last step as 0<=|x| always, you have sandwhiched the supremum between 0 and something that tends to 0, so it must tend to zero, doesn't that show that f(x)-sum ->0 which is what we started with. UNLESS that has something to do with pointwise convergence, which'd make sense (the f(n) being the points)

Comment: I have seen most of them, I'm reading up on the definitions, I suppose I'm just not that confident with them, I long for more exercises to hone myself on. Regardless this "uniform [something]" pops up a lot, what does uniform mean in maths?

Comment: @AlecTeal I am including some more details.

Comment: What was the wink for by the way? If you can recommend lecture notes (PDF form would be spoiling me) or a better/decent book, I've come from physics you see, but I hate the lack of proof, so I've decided to try and do maths; maybe eventually switch.

Comment: And finally, the 25 rep cannot thank you enough, you've helped me a great deal! I'll post a pic of my work if you like to prove I am trying to learn?

Comment: [Rudin's PofMA](http://books.google.ie/books?id=kwqzPAAACAAJ) is usually considered as a good start.

Comment: I honestly don't care about the rep. I believe, and I like the fact that you are trying to learn: congrats.

Comment: @AlecTeal Finally, it you are self-studying, I suggest that you say so when you post a question in the future: people will be more likely to give you an appropriate help.

Comment: I got almost there! It was nice using results like if a series converges absolutely then it converges, I enjoyed doing that, I also liked using "if a sequence is monotonically increasing and bounded above (and below) then it converges" and the bound I have need not be the lowest upper bound. Anyway the step for the $\sum_{n=k+1}^\infity$ at the end, I am happy that the series converges but I am not sure how to show as $k\rightarrow\infity$ that it tends to zero from the definition of convergence (either as a limit or Cauchy) can you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Nevermind, I was being silly as for all e>0 there exists an N such that n>N => |$S_n$-L|<e, noting that $S_n-L$ is -$(\sum^\infty_{i=n+1})$ it is clear that for all e>0 there exists an N such that n>N => |$\sum^\infty_{i=n+1}$|<e, which is the definition of tending to zero for $\sum^\infty_{i=n+1}$ tending to zero.

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, you are correct.